# Xamarin Fragment instantiation causes Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I’m trying to create a bottom navigation view for an android app in Xamarin based on this [tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/).

The tutorial does not explain how to instantiate a `Fragment` properly. It uses a `Fragment.NewInstance` method, which doesn’t exist in a class which inherits from `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`. After a little research I discovered, that this was a static method, which was not mentioned in the tutorial. This method basically instantiates the Fragment.
With this knowledge, I created the following class:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;

namespace Arbitrary
{
    [Register("arbitrary.ArbitraryFragment")]
    public class ArbitraryFragment : Fragment
    {
        public ArbitraryFragment() 
            : base()
        {
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ArbitraryFragment, null);
        }

        public static ArbitraryFragment NewInstance()
        {
            return new ArbitraryFragment() { Arguments = new Bundle() };
        }

    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity`, I tried to instantiate my Fragment using the `NewInstance` method. But the method throws a `ClassNotFoundException` when it is trying to execute the constructor. I read that you had to use the `Register`-Attribute to prevent such an error. The `string` passed in the argument should correspond to the naming convention of Java. I did that in my Fragment class, but still get mentioned Exception.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try applying the workarouund in this bug report: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: If it's not related to this known issue, then it could be a caching issue looking for a md5 hash rather than the registered ACW name.

Comment: Please show the log, I have tried the tutorial and download the demo from github, it works well, please show the detail error not picture, copy it and paste in your post.

Comment: Can you show the code where you make the fragment transaction?

Comment: I feel pretty stupid know. After cleaning the project and rebuilding it, it worked. Thanks to @JonDouglas I figured that out. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Do you want me to add an answer?

Comment: @JonDouglas Sure i can then mark yours as the correct answer